# How can't Herman recognize the real Dyle in Charade?

Tags: plot-explanation, charade

In [Charade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charade_(1963_film)), Cary Grant has a bunch of names. He actually is an embassy employee but it's unknown during the movie. His second name is "DYLE" Which is a member of O.S.S.

But in the movie, Herman (George Kennedy) Called to Lampert (Audrey Hepburn) and said to her that the real name of Cary Grant is "DYLE". But how could it be possible? Herman and Dyle were friends in WW2, so He must recognize the real Dyle who was played by Walter Matthau.

Is this a mistake in the movie or a miss-understanding?

Comment: so your question is "Is it  a bug that  Cary Grant have so many names"?

Comment: @AnkitSharma No! "But how could it be possible? Herman and Dyle was friends in W.W.2. So He must recognize real Dyle which played by Walter Matthau."

Comment: Is the new title appropriate to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand...

Herman Scobie (George Kennedy) merely asks if "Dyle" is there...presumably referring to cary Grant's character.

This is because, as Grant's character reveals, the three primary villains think Cary Grant's character is Carson Dyle's **brother** ...so he would have the **same last name**.

He tells the same thing to Hepburn.